# Load link in WebView Android

Tags: android, android-webview

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

This is my code for webview. It works fine but when a link is clicked it opens the default browser and does not load the link in webview.

Help me out!

Comment: I suggest going with chrome custom tabs for better support, but the other guy's answer should help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your own WebViewClient to tell the webView wich urls or domanis should handle. Something like this:

```
private class BaseWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if (Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().contains("yourdomain.com.ar")) {
            callback.setWebView(view);
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("yourdomain.com.ar")) {
            callback.setWebView(webView);
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then set it to your webView element:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new BaseWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Overriding the webviewclient method solves it.                                                              
                                                                                                            
 public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: I that case you are opening every url inside your webview from any domain. You probably should handle only your webs inside your webview and let the navigator handle other ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `Activity`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new BaseWebViewClient());

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```